# phpExcel toRichTextObject skips newlines

Tags: php, phpexcel, richtext

I'm unable to get my html text correctly transcripted in my Excel file. 
I've looked into HTML.php and tried to change the breakTag function to insert "\n" instead of PHP_EOL (I'm working on a mac) but it does not work either.
If I change this function to insert "BBBB" instead I can see that string appearing in my cell, so the function is correctly called.
I've also tried the example given in 42richText.php but it does not work either. The three lines are correctly colored but without breakline.
Here is my code

```
$wizard = new PHPExcel_Helper_HTML;
$cellText = $wizard->toRichTextObject('<p>First line</p><p>Second line</p>');
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue($colText.$Row, $cellText);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($colText.$Row)->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells($colText.$Row.':'.$colText.($Row+ $tableRows));
```

As keeping newlines is more imported for comprehension than text enrichment I've written a small function to get rid of html tags but keep line breaks:

```
function getRichTextFromHtml($text){
$text = str_replace("</p>","</p>\n", $text);
$text = preg_replace("/(<\/?)(\w+)([^>]*>)/", " ",$text);
$text = html_entity_decode($text, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
return $text;
```

}

```
    $cellText = getRichTextFromHtml('<p>First line</p><p>Second line</p>');
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('H'.$Row, $cellText);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('H'.$Row)->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('H'.$Row.':'.'I'.($Row+ $tableRows));
```

by calling this function I get my lines correctly splitted in my cell but I loose bold and other enrichment...

Can anyone help?
Thanks

Comment: Unable to replicate, whether I use `"\n"` or `PHP_EOL` in the `breakTag()` method. Strictly speaking, it should probably be `"\n"` rather than `PHP_EOL`, because that's what Excel formats actually store for a line break inside a cell.... I do most of my testing under Linux, and use Windows VMs with different versions of Excel for checking the MS Excel outputs, and don't have a Mac or Excel for Mac, so can't specifically test under that platform

Comment: Could you try changing the `breakTag()` method to `$this->stringData = rtrim($this->stringData) . "\n";`, just in case any trailing spaces are affecting the newline

Comment: Hi Mark,I've tried changing breakTag as you indicate but it doesn't change anything. I've copied the content of my cell to a text file and it gets splitted in two lines. So the \n is correctly in place but not interpreted by Excel on mac.

Comment: Can you create a Rich text run containing a newline (`"\n"`) character using the normal methods?

Comment: in Excel on mac, you must type in Alt+Ctrl+Enter, while on windows I think it's only Alt+Enter.In PhpExcel I've tried several things. I've used the example given in the domumentation at 4.6.38, and change the first part of text and the last one to include NL (replacing single quotes by double quotes) and it gives me rich text without breaking the lines, no matter whether I add an instruction to wrap text before of after setting the cell value.

Comment: I've also tried to simply set a cell a value with a plain text including a NL and it works, or using the filter function that I've written to get rid of HTML tags but keep line breaks and it works also.

Comment: I've generated the file from a PC and it opens correctly and shows the break lines. I've copied this PC file to my mac and the break lines do not appear. I have generated the file on my mac and copied it to a PC, the break lines appear on the PC not on the mac...

Comment: I think I've found a solution, explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43470479/phpexcel-torichtextobject-only-showing-newlines-after-saving-file-again-manually